# How do I get the value of my height and width slider to adjust the size of a grid composed of rectangles ( javaFx and sceneBuilder)?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, simulation, scenebuilder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2wSb.png)I am currently using JavaFX and the scene builder with eclipse. How do I get the value of my height and width slider to adjust the size of a grid composed of rectangles?

here's a the section of my code:
public class Controller {

```
@FXML private AnchorPane grid;
@FXML private Slider heightSlider;
@FXML private Slider widthSlider;
@FXML private Label heightLbl;
@FXML private Label widthLabel;
@FXML private Button robotBtn;

private int space = 1; // space between each rectangle

@FXML public void initialize(){ 

    heightSlider.valueProperty().addListener((observarable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        heightLbl.setText(Double.toString(newValue.intValue()));;
    });
    widthSlider.valueProperty().addListener((observarable1, oldValue1, newValue1) -> {
        widthLabel.setText(Double.toString(newValue1.intValue()));;
    });



    heightSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                Number old_val, Number new_val) {
                    heightSlider.setValue((double) new_val);
            }
        });

    widthSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov,
                Number old_val, Number new_val) {
                    widthSlider.setValue((double) new_val);
            }
        });


    for(int i = 0; i < heightSlider.getValue(); i++) { // columns
        for(int j = 0; j < widthSlider.getValue(); j++) { // rows
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(space+i * 35, space+j*35, 35-2*space, 35-2*space);
            rectangle.setFill(Color.WHITE); // rectangle color
            rectangle.setStroke(Color.GREY); // outline color
            grid.getChildren().add(rectangle);
        }
    }
}
```

Image of grid:

Comment: Please elaborate your question by adding some code snippets which you have tried so far or the stacktrace of the exception you are facing

Comment: Thanks, I've added the section of my code that isn't working, and an image of the grid i would like to change the size of based on the values of the sliders

Comment: @nattadey I have updated my answer. If this is not the problem (if you really are redrawing the grid in another method/callback), you need to post more of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not getting the slider value. You are doing this correctly. Look at the method you are creating the grid in: it's called `initialize`! It is only called once upon startup, and thus the grid is only drawn once.

When you change the value of the sliders after initialization, the grid is not redrawn using the new width and height values.You need to create a method that does this using the new values.

Here's an example of how you can update the grid with the new values:

```
@FXML private AnchorPane grid;
@FXML private Slider heightSlider;
@FXML private Slider widthSlider;
@FXML private Label heightLbl;
@FXML private Label widthLabel;
@FXML private Button robotBtn;

private int space = 1; // space between each rectangle
private ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>(25); //Keeps track of the rectangles we currently have on-screen

@FXML public void initialize(){
        heightSlider.valueProperty().addListener((observarable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            heightLbl.setText(Double.toString(heightSlider.getValue()));
            drawGrid(widthSlider.getValue(), heightSlider.getValue()); // Redraw the grid with the new dimensions
        });
        widthSlider.valueProperty().addListener((observarable1, oldValue1, newValue1) -> {
            widthLabel.setText(Double.toString(widthSlider.getValue()));
            drawGrid(widthSlider.getValue(), heightSlider.getValue()); // Redraw the grid with the new dimensions
        });
}

private void drawGrid(double width, double height){ // Draw grid with the provided dimensions
    if(shapes.size() > 0)
        grid.getChildren().removeAll(shapes);       // We must remove the previous rectangles, not just draw new ones (memory leak, performance)
    shapes.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < (int) height; i++){ // columns
        for(int j = 0; j < (int) width; j++){ // rows
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(space+i*35, space+j*35, 35-2*space, 35-2*space);
            rectangle.setFill(Color.WHITE); // rectangle color
            rectangle.setStroke(Color.GREY); // outline color
            shapes.add(rectangle);
            grid.getChildren().add(rectangle);
        }
    }
}
```